# jQuery Ajax: request content by using $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

in order to avoid that the webpage is fully reloaded whenever an internal link is clicked, I'm using jQuery and AJAX.

```
$(".ajax").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // do not follow link
    var requestPage = "content.php?" + jQuery(this).attr('href').split("?")[1];
    $.get(requestPage, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
});
```

Some of these links are generated by the content.php, looking like

```
<li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=A" title="Link A">Link A</a></li>
<li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=B" title="Link B">Link B</a></li>
<li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=C" title="Link B">Link C</a></li>
```

Now my proplem is, the first time after refreshing the page (by using F5) it works fine, the second time the click function is not invoked at all.

Some similar links in the home.php (so they are not regenerated) use this click function as well, no issue with them.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you show what data contains? Some .ajax anchors?

Comment: data contains the content which is to be shown on the page, so it will be something like "<div id="subnav"><ul><li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=A" title="Link A">Link A</a></li>
<li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=B" title="Link B">Link B</a></li>
<li><a class="ajax" href="home.php?x=1&y=C" title="Link B">Link C</a></li></div><div id="containerForContent">...</div>

Comment: You might save a step by taking a look at jQuery .load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach an event such as *click()* to the dom that loading dynamically. So, It should be [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event delegation. In older versions of jQuery you can use *live()* or *delegate()* instead of *[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)*.

```
$(document).on("click",".ajax",function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // do not follow link
    var requestPage = "content.php?" + jQuery(this).attr('href').split("?")[1];
    $.get(requestPage, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation why? Posting code without an explanation is not particular helpful.